# VBA - '30-12-1899' date always becoming first after sorting

Tags: excel, date, vba

I have written a Sub to sort dates using `Application.WorksheetFunction`. It gets dates from the first column of a worksheet and writes them in the second column. After that it divides them into years and makes from them one string which is written to the Cell `(1,3)`. All works properly except the first date in the second column which is always '30-12-1899'. How is it possible?

```
Function dzien(data As String) As String
    Select Case Day(data)
        Case Is < 10
            dzien = "0" & CStr(Day(data))
        Case Is >= 10
            dzien = CStr(Day(data))
    End Select
End Function
Function miesiac(data As String) As String
    Select Case Month(data)
        Case Is < 10
            miesiac = "0" & CStr(Month(data))
        Case Is >= 10
            miesiac = CStr(Month(data))
    End Select
End Function



Sub Sortuj_daty()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim daty() As String
Dim daty_int() As Long
Dim daty_uporzadkowane() As String
Dim daty_calk As String

Dim wiersz As Integer

wiersz = 0

Do

    wiersz = wiersz + 1
    ReDim daty(wiersz)
    ReDim daty_int(wiersz)
    ReDim daty_uporzadkowane(wiersz)

Loop Until ws.Cells(wiersz + 1, 1).Value = "" Or ws.Cells(wiersz + 1, 1).Value = 0

    ReDim daty_uporzadkowane(wiersz + 1)

daty_calk = ""

    For i = 0 To UBound(daty) - 1
        daty(i) = ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
        daty_int(i) = CDbl(CDate(Format(daty(i), "yyyy-mm-dd")))
    Next i

    For j = 0 To UBound(daty) - 1
        daty_uporzadkowane(j) = CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.Small(daty_int, j + 1))
        ws.Cells(j + 1, 2) = daty_uporzadkowane(j)
    Next j

k = 0

daty_uporzadkowane(UBound(daty_uporzadkowane) - 1) = #1/1/1900#

Do

    Do

        k = k + 1
        If k = 1 Then k = k - 1
        End If
        daty_calk = daty_calk & CStr(dzien(daty_uporzadkowane(k))) & "-" & miesiac(daty_uporzadkowane(k)) & "/"

    Loop Until Year(CDate(daty_uporzadkowane(k))) < Year(CDate(daty_uporzadkowane(k + 1))) Or k = UBound(daty) - 1
        daty_calk = Left(daty_calk, Len(daty_calk) - 1) & "-"
        daty_calk = daty_calk & Year(daty_uporzadkowane(k)) & " / "

Loop Until k = UBound(daty) - 1

        daty_calk = Left(daty_calk, Len(daty_calk) - 3)
        ws.Cells(1,3).Value = daty_calk
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

VBA interprets `1` as the last day of 1899. 
Thus `0` with more fantasy is 30.12.1899. An empty cell is considered 0, if it is parsed to a number. In your case, you are having somewhere in the sorted range an empty cell.

On a new excel file run this small piece of code and you will get it:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print CDate(1)
    Range("A1").ClearContents
    Debug.Print Year(Range("A1")); Month(Range("A1")); Day(Range("A1"))
    Debug.Print Format(0, "yyyy-mm-dd")  '1899-12-30

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for widening my knowledge. I thought that the date 01.01.1999 parsed to a number is 1. When it comes to my macro, I don't have any empty cell in the range of the worksheet which values are assigned to the array.

Comment: @Paweł - Welcome. You should be having either an empty cell or a cell with `0` to get the `30-12-1899`.

Comment: The cells' values are:2018-03-26
2018-02-12
2018-01-25
2017-03-22
2016-03-22
2018-04-22
2018-04-23
2018-04-24
2018-04-25
2018-04-26, so there are neither empty cells nor zeros within the original range

Comment: @Paweł - cool. So when they are sorted is any of these values omitted?

Comment: @Paweł - to see the values you are sorting, implement this command in one of the loops - `Debug.Print "This is the value -> " & daty_int(i)`. Thus the `0` will appear easily :D